# Angular Firestore show data on Input change

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angular2-observables

I'm working on a project with Angular 5 and Firestore using **AngularFire2**. What i'm trying to do is: "As the user enters the Document ID in the first input, the other two fields load automatically by getting the data from Firebase.

**Here is the Image of my form**

[image]

This is just one example, Its easy for me if all the data is in one collection then I just pre-load it in `ngOnInit` but, in some cases I have to display data from other collections as well such as `Users`.

**Here is what I'm doing:**

- I detect the change and call a function `(change)="getPropertyInfo($event)"`
- I call firebase and get the data

code:

```
getPropertyInfo($document_id) {
  this.afs.collection('properties', ref => {
    return ref.where('strata_plan_no', '==', $document_id.target.value);
  }).valueChanges().subscribe(property => {
    if (property[0]) { // if these is any record
      this.jobForm.street_address = property[0]['street_address'];
      this.jobForm.suburb = property[0]['suburb'];
      console.log(property[0]);
      // I have a field called user_id in this property collection as well. 
    }
  });
}
```

Now I also want to get user information using that selected `property_id` which I'm doing like this:

```
getUserByID(id: string): Observable < any > {
  return this.afs.collection('users').doc(id).valueChanges();
}
```

The **Issue** here is that this user is an observable. I'm looking for some way to convert it as an Object so that i can bind it to my User fields in the form as well.

Also, If In case of Users if I subscribe to the observable just like the above code, i won't be able to get data instantly to display as it is async.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and suggest something that I could try.

Thank

**Update**

I followed *DauleDK's* advice. Now I'm using a Reactive forms approach to get more out my form handling, Watched Observable series and have got a reasonable idea of how things are working internally.

Here is what I have now:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.jobsForm.get('property.strata_plan_no')
    .valueChanges
    .sample(Observable.fromEvent(this.strata_plan_no_input.nativeElement, 'blur'))
    .subscribe((strata_plan_no) => {
      this.propertyService.findByStrataPlanNo(strata_plan_no)
        .filter((property) => property !== null) // filter nulls
        .map(property => property[0]) // return the first element of the array
        .subscribe((property) => {
          console.log(property.manager_id); // this log gives me the ID i'm looking for.
          this.managerService.findByID(property.manager_id).subscribe((manager) => { // this subscribe gives me an error
            console.log(manager);
          });
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the Error that I'm getting:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSnapshot' of undefined
at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (fromRef.js:8)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
at ObserveOnOperator.call (observeOn.js:74)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
at Observable.ConnectableObservable.connect (ConnectableObservable.js:43)
at RefCountOperator.call (refCount.js:25)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
at MapOperator.call (map.js:57)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going into details, you should explore observables more, to solve your problem. I think you should look into [switchmap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) combined with reactive forms, to solve your problem. Then you can leverage from observables:

Something like this:

```
this.jobForm.get('documentIdControl').valueChanges() // Subscribe to value changes from form
.switchmap((documentId: string) => this.afs.doc(`properties/${documentId}`, ref => ref.where('strata_plan_no', '==', $document_id.target.value)))
.filter((property) => property !== null) // Include if you only wan't, if different from null.
.do((property) => {
   this.jobForm.street_address = property.street_address;
   this.jobForm.suburb = property.suburb;
})
.subscribe();
```

One resource I can highly recommend to improve your usage of observables, is this [youtube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9wOu11uU6U) on the topic :) When you have a solid understanding of Observables, then you can really profit from Firestore and angularfire2. Let me know if you have any questions, and if you create a stackblitz I can help with the details :)

Comment: please check my updated question. I've followed your advice and tried to make things work but, i'm getting this error that I can't figure why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are still missing the switchmap I see. This is a very powerfull operator. It takes the value of the observable above (i.e. the value from your form), and then creates a new Observable. You should look at this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularfire-db-api-fbad9p, with an explanation here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md. Its very close to what you are creating :)